Would someone like to fix the now-broken link to historiography on the Topics help page?
There is a link to "historiography" at https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic which points to http://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/writing/history/critical/historiography.html which gives a 404 not found error.
Is this the right place to ask if someone would like to fix that?

Done - I've replaced it with the Internet Archive link.
In general it's best practice to use these instead of live links due to link rot.
